# Get a list of PRs for a milestone using Github API

Tags: github, github-api

I have looked through the documentation and I can see the Github UI can get a list of PRs that are linked to a milestone eg/ `https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/milestone/48` but how do you do that from the API?

You can access a milestone via the API eg/ `https://api.github.com/repos/X/Y/milestones/1` but it doesn't contain the PRs for it or provide a link to get the PRs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [issue search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues) to return all issues in a milestone. The [search syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-by-milestone-on-an-issue-or-pull-request) for finding issues by milestone is `milestone:<milestone name>`.

Comment: Sure it does—does your token have `repo` scope?

Comment: My bad, typo :)

Comment: The url to get this to work was `https://api.github.com/search/issues\?q\=milestone:milestonename+type:pr+repo:testuser/testrepo`

Comment: Came here after having problems searching for issues under a specific milestone via PyGithub. The problem for me was the milestone title needed to be enclosed in double quotes, inside the string semi-quotes. So, `..., milestone='"Version 1.1.8"'`

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy to [install Github's `gh` command](https://github.com/cli/cli), you can get a list of your open milestones like this:

```
gh api repos/:owner/:repo/milestones --jq '.[].title'
```

And once you know the name of the milestone (**such as 2.37.0 in the example here**), you can use this commend to get just a list of merged PR titles:

```
gh pr list --search "milestone:2.37.0" --state merged --json title --jq '.[].title'
```

The `gh` command supports `jq` queries and also Go Lang templating, so you can probably make the data it'll output look like anything you might want (eg, a nice markdown list).